# Calling  the web service (Tomcat) from the web service (IIS) takes a long time

Tags: performance, web-services, iis, tomcat, service

Here is my performance problem. An IIS Web service calls via SOAP request (hhtps) the web service running on TomCat. The first call takes about 4-6 seconds all the other less than 1 sec. Directly call from the client or through SOAPUI takes ca. 600-700ms.

I have already tried the different configurations in IIS  => without success.
Why is it so? Is there a fix / workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: In your title you suggest that a Web Service in Tomcat is calling a Web Service in IIS. However, your question body suggests the opposite. Which is it? How is the Web Service in IIS implemented? .NET (presumably)?

Comment: O! Sorry! It is IIS-Service that calls Tomcat-Service. Yes, it is C#.